# How to resolve "The 'pip' distribution was not" when using pyenv on Mac

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, pyenv

I'm attempting to install codalab worksheets cli. I have a Mac M2 machine, with a python version 3.10 installed through homebrew. I tried just `pip install`ing the codalab package, but it didn't work and some digging showed that codalab might not work yet on python 3.10. In one of the [codalab CI](https://github.com/codalab/codalab-worksheets/blob/master/.github/workflows/release.yml) yamls I saw that python version 3.7 is specified, so I installed `pyenv`, configured my python homebrew installation in it, and got python 3.7. Running `pyenv versions` I get:

```
  system
  3.7.17
  3.8.17
* 3.10 --> /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10 (set by /Users/a/.pyenv/version)
```

(I also tried 3.8). However, doing `pip install codalab` after the right python version was chosen with `pyenv global ..` fails on the following error:

```
      pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip' distribution was not found and is required by the application
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

When I run `pip --version` and `python --version` I get the expected values:

```
pip 23.2 from /Users/a/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Python 3.7.17
```

I looked this error up online and people always seem to have pip missing from their `PATH` or something but I have it there (in the pyenv shims).
Thanks for any help.

Comment: just be explicit `python -m pip install ....`

Comment: Same error @JoranBeasley